# Add class to element if it contains just one specific number

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to add a class to a string of it contains just one zero.

I was trying something like this but can't make it work:

```
$(".stockinfo.col4").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === "0";
}).addClass("orderitem");
```

HTML:

```
<div class="stockinfo col4"><strong>Stock</strong>: 0<span></span></div>
```

Whats the best way to do this?

Edit: This works- but throws an error if it wont match a zero only in the string. Could use it but I dont like to have the error in the console- makes me nervous

```
$(".stockinfo.col4").filter(function() {
 console.log($(this).text().trim().match(/0/g).length)
  if ($(this).text().trim().match(/0/g).length == 1) {
  $(".stockinfo.col4").addClass("orderitem")
 }
});
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
```

Comment: [demo with 2 00](https://jsfiddle.net/k0fobn6u/) | [demo with 1 0](https://jsfiddle.net/k0fobn6u/1/) check this demo hope it helps

Comment: @guradio the demo works for me - it does throw an error if the string doesn't match a zero only: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Comment: @user2059370 i added condition check [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/k0fobn6u/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".stockinfo.col4").filter(function() {
  if($(this).text().trim().match(/0/g)){//check if there is 0
  return ($(this).text().trim().match(/0/g).length == 1)//count number of 0
  }

}).addClass("orderitem");//add class
```

You have to first check if there is 0 in the string. if there is 0 count if == 1 then add the class

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/k0fobn6u/2/)

Comment: just realized this will give a class when its a zero in the number, not just a zero. It the value is 10 it will give the class and so on - I need it to only give the class when its a single zero.  Logged in on another account, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

*Your code should work.* However in my opinion you can place the value in `span` element then use `find()` to check.

```js
$(".stockinfo.col4").filter(function() {
  return $(this).find('span').text().trim() === "0";
}).addClass("orderitem");
```

```css
.orderitem{
  color:red
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stockinfo col4"><strong>Stock</strong>: <span>0</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I can´t place the value myself unfortunaly - I have to work with the exact HTML structure so targeting the span element doesn´t work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex for that like following.

```js
$(".stockinfo.col4").filter(function () {
    return ($(this).text().match(/0/g) || []).length == 1;
}).addClass("orderitem");
```

```css
.orderitem {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stockinfo col4"><strong>Stock</strong>: 0<span></span></div>
<div class="stockinfo col4"><strong>Stock</strong>: 000<span></span></div>
<div class="stockinfo col4"><strong>Stock</strong>: 1<span></span></div>
```

**UPDATE:** for adding class to just 0.

```js
$(".stockinfo.col4").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().split(':')[1].trim() == '0';
}).addClass("orderitem");
```

```css
.orderitem {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stockinfo col4"><strong>Stock</strong>: 0<span></span></div>
<div class="stockinfo col4"><strong>Stock</strong>: 000<span></span></div>
<div class="stockinfo col4"><strong>Stock</strong>: 1<span></span></div>
<div class="stockinfo col4"><strong>Stock</strong>: 10<span></span></div>
```

Comment: @Azim this will give a class when its a zero in the value, not just a zero. Is the value is 10 it will give the class and so on - I need it to only give the class when its a single zero. Realized that the accepted answer is not working for me.  Logged in on another account, sorry for that.

Comment: @Azim you can see in the fiddle here - it will give the class to all values with a single zero - 10,20,30 etc: https://jsfiddle.net/06cLkq2k/ it should only give the class to the single zero value.